# Central Limit Theorem Exercise!

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,...,X_{36} \overset{i.i.d}{\sim}  \mbox{Poisson}(1)$ . Find $P( X< 1.1)$ by

(a) using the central limit theorem of $\bar{X}$;

(b) using the exact distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{36} X_i $.

I only need help with the approximate distribution of $\bar{X}$. I believe is distributed Normal as $N\sim(\lambda, \sqrt{\lambda})$ were $\lambda = 1$

Since I have $36$ $X$ vars I get $N\sim(1*36, \sqrt{1*36})$ $=$ $N\sim(36, 6)$

Or is it $N\sim(1, 1/36)$?

Am I up to a good start or am I lost?

EDIT:

Using $N\sim(1, 1/36)$ for (a) I got $P(Z < 0.6) = \mbox{pnorm}(0.6)$ Using $R$ software I got $.0726$

for (b) I'm doing the following:

$\bar{X} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{36} X_i \sim \mbox{Poisson}(36)$ Hence $P(\bar{X} < 1.1) = P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{36} X_i < 1.1\right) $

In $R$ I'm trying $\mbox{ppois}(1.1, 36)$ But I get an outrageous low number. If I however try $\mbox{ppois}(1.1, 1)$ I get $0.736$  which very close to the answer for (a).

Is there something else that needs to be done here?

Comment: The distribution of $\bar{X}$ is reasonably close to normal, mean $1$, variance $\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I added some more answers, will you be able to point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You are on the right track. The reason why your answers are very different is you are answering a different question in (b). $P(\bar{X}<1.1)=P(\Sigma_{i=1}^{36}X_{i}<36*1.1)$, not what you have written

Comment: Your answer for a) should be about $0.7257$. Probably a typo. For b) the sum is Poisson mean $36$. The probability that $\bar{X}\lt 1.1$ is the probability that a Poisson mean $36$ is less than $(36)(1.1)$, This is the probability the Poisson mean $36$ is $\le 39$, or $\lt 40$. Now you can get the answer from software. The Poisson mean $1$ being less than $1.1$ should not work, anyway $\bar{X}$ is not Poisson.

Comment: @KenDunn Thank you, that makes more sense. and the probabilities are almost the same.